# Simple Python Contact Info Book

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic contact information book with python. The user can search or add contacts. Here is my code.

```
address_book = {}
print('''1 - Add/Update contact
2 - Search
''')

def update_contact():
    name = input("Enter a name: ")
    phone_number = input("Enter a phone number: ")
    address_book[name] = phone_number
def search():
    search_key = input("Search for a name: ")
    for key, value in address_book.items():
        if key == search_key:
            print("Name:" + search_key)
            print("Phone Number: " + address_book[search_key])
            return
        else:
            print("No such contact was found in the address book")
            return
run = True
def quitfunc():
    global run
    print("Program Stopped.")
    run = False

while (run):
    print("")
    option = input("Choose a option: ")
    if (option == "1"):
        print("")
        update_contact()
        
    elif (option == "2"):
        print("")
        search()
        
    else:
        quitfunc()
```

The update_contact function works fine, but the search function only works for the first person you search up. If you try to make a second contact, the search function doesn't work with that person. What is wrong if my code? Thanks!

Comment: When `def search():` is called, how many times can it `return` for each time it is called? What happens when a `return` statement is reached? Do you see why this causes a problem for your logic?

Comment: You’re searching for a key in a dictionary. You do not need to loop over the entire dict for that. You can simply directly access the dict key. That’s the point of dicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead for your search function:

```
def search():
    search_key = input("Search for a name: ")
    if search_key in address_book:
        print("Name:", search_key);
        print("Phone number:", address_book[search_key])
    else:
        print("No such contact was found in the address book")
```

You don't need to iterate over a for loop in order to search for a key in the dictionary. A simple `if..in` statement works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if key == search_key:
            print("Name:" + search_key)
            print("Phone Number: " + address_book[search_key])
            return
else:
            print("No such contact was found in the address book")
            return
```

The issue here is that you have added a return statement in the else part as well. so what happens is that, it checks for the first value, if its not found it executes the return statement and comes out of the function. So, I'd consider removing the return statement in else.

Return statement is not really necessary but if you want to add it, add it outside the for loop.